# How to loop through 2 different list dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two lists Coming from Firebase, I want to check if the value in the First list is in the second list then add the index of the value to an empty list

```
List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> relatedAccount = [];
  List<Map> relatedAccountShow = [];
  gg() async {
    // List<Map<String, dynamic>> relatedAccount = [];
    final getmyAcct =
        await firestore.collection('users').doc(auth.currentUser!.uid).get();
    final result = await firestore
        .collection('users')
        .where("id", isNotEqualTo: auth.currentUser!.uid)
        .get();
    final relatedAccount = result.docs;

    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 6));
    print('this all users accoutn =====>  ${relatedAccount.length}');
    relatedAccount.shuffle();
    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 6));
    final usersInterest = (getmyAcct.data()!['interest'] as List)
        .map((item) => item as String)
        .toList();
    for (var i = 0; i < relatedAccount.length; i++) {
      final acct = relatedAccount[i].data();
     
      for (var j = 0; j < acct[i]['interest'].length; j++) {
        if (acct['interest'].contains(usersInterest[j])) {
          print('this from loop =====>  ${acct[i][j]}');
           relatedAccountShow.add(acct[i]);
        } 
       }
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is the issue you are getting from above code

Comment: @SankethB.K so i want to check if one of the value of 1st list is in the 2 list  the add the user to another list.. but is given me null value

Comment: Which variable is null?

Comment: @SankethB.K  both acct[i][j]; or acct[i];

Answer (score 0):

May be the following solution will work for you, I am not sure about your actual problem:

```
final List<Map<String, dynamic>> list1 = <Map<String, dynamic>>[
      {'id': 'a', 'value': 'apple'},
      {'id': 'b', 'value': 'pen'},
      {'id': 'c', 'value': 'table'},
    ];

    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> list2 = <Map<String, dynamic>>[
      {'id': 'q', 'value': 'apple'},
      {'id': 'b', 'value': 'pen'},
      {'id': 'a', 'value': 'table'},
    ];

    final List<int> listCommonItems = <int>[];

    for (int index = 0; index < list1.length; index++) {
      if (list2.any(
        (Map<String, dynamic> element) => element['id'] == list1[index]['id'],
      )) {
        listCommonItems.add(index);
      }
    }
```

Comment: let me see if the sweep this to work for me